# efficient asp.net sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

Been using this site for years and have always found it very helpful and normally all my questions get answered by reading the site.

I have some case studies on a site than need to be related to other sections of the site and i am using this code to pull the records from the database :-

```
    <div id="sidebar">
  <asp:accessdatasource
    id="cskey"
    runat="server"
    datasourcemode="DataSet"
    datafile="_db/db.mdb"
    selectcommand="SELECT id FROM markets_case_assign WHERE productid = @catid">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="catid" QueryStringField="id" DefaultValue="1" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:accessdatasource>
  <asp:Repeater id="cskeycontent" runat="server" DataSourceID="cskey">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("id")%>'></asp:Label>
      <asp:accessdatasource
    id="csval"
    runat="server"
    datasourcemode="DataSet"
    datafile="_db/db.mdb"
    selectcommand="SELECT id,title,company FROM casestudies WHERE id = @pid">
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:controlparameter name="pid" controlid="Label1" DefaultValue="1" />
        </SelectParameters>
      </asp:accessdatasource>
      <asp:Repeater id="csvalcontent" runat="server" DataSourceID="csval">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="case-studies">
            <h2><%#Eval("company")%></h2>
            <p><%#Eval("title")%></p>
            <p class="no-margin-bottom"><a href="case-study.aspx?id=<%#Eval("id")%>" class="read-more">Read case study</a></p>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

I was just wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers Andy

Comment: More simple than this minimal repeater ? Do you have something else on your mind ? maybe you try to do that many times and look for a template kind ?

Comment: hey man thanks for the reply.

i was wondering if there was a way of doing it with only one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i was wondering if there was a way of doing it with only one query

To make it one query, just change the SQL call as:

```
SELECT id,title,company FROM casestudies 
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM markets_case_assign WHERE productid = @catid)
```

and use only one repeater (the inner one).

Now you lose the extra advanced to separate them with some extra header, line etc..